# Adding multiple feature classes (all within file geodatabase) to group layer using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, feature-class, group-layer, addlayer

I am currently trying to add all the feature classes contained within a gdb to a group layer in ArcGIS Pro via a script. I have however not managed to add more than one single feature class at a time.

By looking at the script below, do you have any suggestions about how to solve this?

```
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\TEST_ENV\\AGOL_output\\AGOL.gdb"
datasets = arcpy.ListDatasets(feature_type='feature')
datasets = [''] + datasets if datasets is not None else []
rootPath_aprx = 'C:\\TEST_ENV\\AGOL_output\\'
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(rootPath_aprx + 'WMStest1.aprx')
aprxMap = aprx.listMaps("Map")[0]
targetGroupLayer = aprxMap.listLayers('Group1')[0]
for ds in datasets:
    for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_dataset=ds):
        path = os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace, ds, fc)
        print(path)
        for GroupLayer in targetGroupLayer:
            # print(l)
            if str(GroupLayer) == GroupName:
                try:
                    aprxMap.addLayerToGroup(aprxMap, targetGroupLayer, path, ['AUTO_ARRANGE'])
                except:
                    print("gah.")
aprx.save()
```

The error I am receiving when I run the script is:

> for GroupLayer in targetGroupLayer: TypeError: 'Layer' object is not
> iterable

Answer (score 0):

You are setting:

```
targetGroupLayer = aprxMap.listLayers('Group1')[0]
```

The index of 0 means that you are setting `targetGroupLayer` to the first item in the list returned by `listLayers` i.e. `targetGroupLayer` is being set to a Layer object.

You then use:

```
for GroupLayer in targetGroupLayer:
```

to try and iterate a Layer object which inevitably gives you `TypeError: 'Layer' object is not iterable`.